# Python: Making a dictionary with items of two columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, group-by

I have a dataset like this:

```
user_id           time_location
  13            (2018-02-02, 190)
  12            (2018-06-02, 194)
  13            (2018-06-02, 194)
  16            (2018-02-02, 190)
  17            (2018-02-02, 190)
  11            (2018-05-02, 198)
  19            (2018-02-02, 190)
  15            (2018-05-02, 198)
  15            (2018-06-02, 194)
```

What I want to have is a list of dictionaries that keys are items in "time_location" column and values are user_id 's of each key. Here is a sample output:

```
List=[{(2018-02-02, 190): 13, 16,17,19},{(2018-06-02, 194): 12,13,15},{(2018-05-02, 198): 11,15}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [13, 12, 13, 16, 17, 11, 19, 15, 15],
                   'time_location': [('2018-02-02', 190), ('2018-06-02', 194),
                                     ('2018-06-02', 194), ('2018-02-02', 190),
                                     ('2018-02-02', 190), ('2018-05-02', 198),
                                     ('2018-02-02', 190), ('2018-05-02', 198),
                                     ('2018-06-02', 194)]})

d = defaultdict(list)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    d[row['time_location']].append(row['user_id'])

d = [{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]

# [{('2018-02-02', 190): [13, 16, 17, 19]},
#  {('2018-06-02', 194): [12, 13, 15]},
#  {('2018-05-02', 198): [11, 15]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `df.groupby()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [13, 12, 13, 16, 17, 11, 19, 15, 15],
                   'time_location': [('2018-02-02', 190), ('2018-06-02', 194),
                                     ('2018-06-02', 194), ('2018-02-02', 190),
                                     ('2018-02-02', 190), ('2018-05-02', 198),
                                     ('2018-02-02', 190), ('2018-05-02', 198),
                                     ('2018-06-02', 194)]})

d = df.groupby('time_location')['user_id'].apply(list).to_dict()
d = [{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]

# [{('2018-02-02', 190): [13, 16, 17, 19]},
#  {('2018-05-02', 198): [11, 15]},
#  {('2018-06-02', 194): [12, 13, 15]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
listOfDict = []
for pair in your_dataset: ## I'm assuming your data is a list of lists/tuples
    listOfDict.append({pair[1]: pair[0]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with `group_by`

```
df.groupby("time_location")["user_id"].apply(list).to_dict()
```